Django bulk upload takes 30 seconds to process 100 of records
I have working on a travel insurance project, by which on my requirements is to allow agents to bulk upload travellers with pre-bought policies and packages. I have somehow managed to create this process, but unfortunately 100 rows of excel sheet takes 30 seconds to process. Its very bad in user experiences, most of the agents will be uploading 1000 travellers per month atleast. Please help on pointing out the issue and how this can be optimised further ?
This is flow:
Admin -> Creates Benefits ( For ex: Medical Expense, theft etc)
Admin -> Create Policy -> Attach Package (one policy can many package) -> Choose Benefits and its limits -> Done
(Note: Each benefit will have allocated amount stored in PackageBenefit table while creating Policy)
Agents -> Upload Traveller via Excel
Excel -> User -> Traveller -> PolicyHolder (traveller who bought policy) ->PolicyUsage (this is where i store Package details, Benefits and its allocated amount)
These are the models
User

Traveller (1-1 with user)
Policy
Package (Foreign with Policy)
Benefits
PackageBenefit (Foreign with Policy, Package, this holds max_allocated money for the benefit in package)
PolicyHolder (Stores all information when traveller buys/attaches to a policy, foreign with traveller, policy, package)
PolicyUsage (Foreign with Policy, Package, max_allocated and gets created when traveller gets attached to policy)

So far, I am using pandas to preprocess the excel sheet and also do validation here itself. Once validation is done, i am creating bulk uploads. This is my code;
def bulk_upload_traveller(request):
    form = AddTravellerProfileForm()

    if request.method == "POST" and request.FILES["file"]:
        file = request.FILES["file"]

        # Read the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(file)

        except Exception as e:
            return messages.error(request, "Failed to read Excel file, please re-check the file and try again")

        # Limiting the number of records per upload to 100
        if len(df) > 100:
            return messages.error(request, "Exceeded maximum limit of 100 records per upload. You can upload 100 records per upload, please try again with limited records")

        # Checking mandatory rows and values
        required_fields = ["name", "passport_no", "id_card_no", "dob", "departure_date", "return_date", "ecert_no", "policy_id", "package_id"]
        missing_records = df[df[required_fields].isnull().any(axis=1)]
        if not missing_records.empty:
            missing_indices = missing_records.index.tolist()
            missing_columns = missing_records[required_fields].isnull().any()
            missing_column_names = missing_columns[missing_columns].index.tolist()

            messages.error(request, f"Missing values is found in the records: {missing_indices}, columns: {missing_column_names}. Please resolve and restart bulk uploading process again")
            return render(request, "administrator/user_management/travellers/traveller_bulk_upload/bulk_upload_failure.html")

        # Validate date formats
        invalid_date_records = df[~df["departure_date"].apply(validate_date_format) | ~df["dob"].apply(validate_date_format) | ~df["return_date"].apply(validate_date_format)]

        if not invalid_date_records.empty:
            invalid_indices = invalid_date_records.index.tolist()
            messages.error(request, f"Invalid date format in records: {invalid_indices}")
            return render(request, "administrator/user_management/travellers/traveller_bulk_upload/bulk_upload_failure.html")

        # Check if policy_id and package_id are valid
        _policies = {policy.id: (policy.policy_name, policy.policy_code) for policy in Policy.objects.all()}
        _packages = {package.id: (package.package_name, package.package_code, package.validity) for package in Package.objects.all()}

        valid_policy_ids = set(_policies.keys())
        valid_package_ids = set(_packages.keys())
        invalid_policy_records = df[~df["policy_id"].isin(valid_policy_ids)]
        invalid_policy_indices = invalid_policy_records.index.tolist()

        invalid_package_records = df[~df["package_id"].isin(valid_package_ids)]
        invalid_package_indices = invalid_package_records.index.tolist()

        _policy_pack_error_messages = []

        if invalid_policy_indices:
            _policy_pack_error_messages.append(f"Invalid policy IDs found at indices: {invalid_policy_indices}")

        if invalid_package_indices:
            _policy_pack_error_messages.append(f"Invalid package IDs found at indices: {invalid_package_indices}")

        # Show error messages
        if _policy_pack_error_messages:
            error_message = ". ".join(_policy_pack_error_messages)
            messages.error(request, error_message)
            return render(request, "administrator/user_management/travellers/traveller_bulk_upload/bulk_upload_failure.html")

        # Autogenerate username if empty
        df.loc[df["username"].isnull(), "username"] = df["name"].str.lower().str.replace(" ", "_")

        # Autogenerate email if empty
        df.loc[df["email"].isnull(), "email"] = df["username"].str.lower().str.replace(" ", "_") + "@ksa.alkhairicare.com"

        # Autogenerate password if empty
        df.loc[df["password"].isnull(), "password"] = df["passport_no"].str.lower().str.replace(" ", "_")

        # Convert DataFrame to list of dictionaries
        records = df.to_dict(orient="records")

        # Create objects in bulk
        users = []
        travellers = []
        policy_holders = []
        for index, record in enumerate(records, start=1):
            try:
                _password = make_password(record["password"])
                user = User(username=record["username"], email=record["email"], entity_name=record["name"], password=_password, role=CUSTOMERS)
                users.append(user)

                traveller = Traveller(
                    user=user,
                    name=record["name"],
                    passport_no=record["passport_no"],
                    id_card_no=record["id_card_no"],
                    dob=record["dob"],
                    primary_email=record["email"],
                    is_approved=True,
                )
                traveller.gender = record["gender"] if "gender" in record else ""
                traveller.nationality = record["nationality"] if "nationality" in record else ""
                traveller.country = record["country"] if "country" in record else ""
                traveller.hp_no = record["hp_no"] if "hp_no" in record else ""
                travellers.append(traveller)

                policy_id = record["policy_id"]
                package_id = record["package_id"]
                policy_name, policy_code = _policies.get(policy_id, ("", ""))
                package_name, package_code, package_validity = _packages.get(package_id, ("", "", 0))

                departure_date = pd.to_datetime(record["departure_date"]).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
                total_validity_days = int(package_validity)
                validity_end = departure_date + pd.Timedelta(days=total_validity_days)
                validity_end_final = validity_end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

                policy_holder = PolicyHolder(
                    traveller=traveller,
                    policy_id=record["policy_id"],
                    package_id=record["package_id"],
                    policy_name=policy_name,
                    package_name=package_name,
                    policy_code=policy_code,
                    package_code=package_code,
                    holder_name=record["name"],
                    total_validity=package_validity,
                    validity_start=departure_date,
                    validity_end=validity_end_final,
                    payment_status="manual",
                    departure_date=record["departure_date"],
                    return_date=record["return_date"],
                    ecert_no=record["ecert_no"],
                )
                policy_holders.append(policy_holder)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error occurred while processing record {index}: {e}")
                messages.error(request, f"Error occurred while processing record {index}: {e}")

        # Bulk create objects
        total_objects_added = len(users) + len(travellers) + len(policy_holders)
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                User.objects.bulk_create(users)
                Traveller.objects.bulk_create(travellers)
                PolicyHolder.objects.bulk_create(policy_holders)

                policy_usages = []

                # Fetch all PackageBenefit objects
                all_package_benefits = PackageBenefit.objects.all()

                # Create a dictionary to store PackageBenefit objects based on package ID
                package_benefits_dict = {}
                for package_benefit in all_package_benefits:
                    package_id = package_benefit.package_id
                    if package_id not in package_benefits_dict:
                        package_benefits_dict[package_id] = []
                    package_benefits_dict[package_id].append(package_benefit)

                for policy_holder in policy_holders:

                    package_id = policy_holder.package_id
                    package_benefits = package_benefits_dict.get(package_id, [])

                    for package_benefit in package_benefits:
                        policy_usage = PolicyUsage(
                            policy_holder=policy_holder,
                            package_id=policy_holder.package_id,
                            benefit_id=package_benefit.benefit_id,
                            benfit_name=package_benefit.benefit.name,
                            actual_limit=package_benefit.actual_limit,
                            remaining_limit=package_benefit.actual_limit,
                            currency=package_benefit.currency,
                        )
                        policy_usages.append(policy_usage)

                PolicyUsage.objects.bulk_create(policy_usages)

            messages.success(request, "Bulk upload process was succeessfully completed.", extra_tags="success")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Unknown error occurred:", e)
            messages.error(request, f"Failed to complete bulk transaction: {e}")

        context = {"total": total_objects_added, "user_count": len(users), "traveller_count": len(travellers), "po_count": len(policy_holders)}
        return render(request, "administrator/user_management/travellers/traveller_bulk_upload/bulk_upload_success.html", context)

    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "administrator/user_management/travellers/traveller_bulk_upload/bulk_upload_form.html", context)

Let me know if i need to share anything else, and this is my first question on stackoverflow. Sorry if its in wrong format

What database do you use? Might have something to do with indexes?

I am using Postgres, i havent explicitly mentioned any index as of now. Do you think it can help ?

Can you install Django Debug Toolbar, and check how many SQL statements are being executed, along with whether any of them are particularly slow?

An alternative solution would be to use line profiler, which can tell how long each line takes.

It's fairly hard to tell what might be slow here. For example, you're loading every Policy object with Policy.objects.all(), and that could be slow if there are many Policy objects. You need to profile this to figure out what is worth optimizing.

I have added toolbar to check the query timings, i can see the bulk_create takes time. Rest seems normal, is this normal like 30 seconds ? whats average to upload 100 records ? And i am processing 3 to 4 joints
